# How to make reference in JSON object with in itself to some other key-value pair?

Tags: json

I need to make condition on the next key-value pair regarding to prev key-value value pair existed on json object. And I tried like below -

```
var json = {'numeric':true,
            'required' : !json.numeric
}
```

Of course this doesnot work. I need to write this by two successive steps like below -

```
var json = {'numeric':true};
json.required = !json.numeric;
```

Is there any way to acheive first thing.

Comment: Not really, either that or assign the value to another variable and use that but still a two liner. The object doesn't "exist" until after it it is evaluated and therefore cannot be referenced